# REG EXP PHP. Remove break lines if at the end of the line before is not a dot there

Tags: php, regex

I got this text

`possono 
 godere 
 di la spiaggia, situato a 7 km da il porto         turistico di A , a 5 chilometri da l'aeroporto di 
 B.
ALBERGO: formato da monolocali, appartamenti con`

And I need something like this with preg_replace

`possono godere di la spiaggia, situato a 7 km da il porto turistico di A, a 5 chilometri da l'aeroporto di B.
ALBERGO: formato da monolocali, appartamenti con`

I use regular expressions like `'/[^\.]\n/'` but it takes the space after 'B.' too.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: You should first figure out if you have standard *line breaks* or CRLF everywhere. Also better use a lookbehind for the period.

Comment: Please see https://ideone.com/mNvHfk that I came up with during [the chat with Armali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912127/reg-exp-php-remove-break-lines-if-at-the-end-of-the-line-before-is-not-a-dot-th/40921385?noredirect=1#comment84983806_40921385). If it is what you need, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$str = 'possono 
 godere 
 di la spiaggia, situato a 7 km da il porto         turistico di A , a 5 chilometri da l\'aeroporto di 
 B.
ALBERGO: formato da monolocali, appartamenti con';
$res = preg_replace('~\s+(?!^[A-Z]+:)~um', ' ', $str);
echo $res;
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/G74wQK)

The `\s+(?!^[A-Z]+:)` matches:

- `\s+`  - 1 or more whitespaces that are not immediately followed with...
- `(?!^[A-Z]+:)` - start of line (`^`, `m` modifier makes `^` match the beginning of a line instead of a string), 1+ uppercase ASCII letters (see `[A-Z]+`) and a `:`.

The `/u` modifier is used just in case the strings contain Unicode letters. Also, in that case, replace `[A-Z]` with `\p{Lu}`.

Comment: Does it work or do you need more details/help/insight?

Comment: It just doesn't change `A ,` to `A,`.

Comment: @Armali In my answer, I addressed the issue stated in the title, although it is based on the OP contents. Perhaps, a more appropriate solution will be https://ideone.com/mNvHfk

Comment: ... no more complaints from my side. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this process should be split up into more tasks. My proposal:

1. Tidy up all whitespace sequences `(\s+)` and normalize them to one standard space (remember to set the "global" flag).
2. Restructure the text by identifying semantic markers like `"ALBERGO: "` and place a line feed `\n` before it. You could even search for `". ALBERGO: "` and replace it by `".\nALBERGO: "`
3. Standardize (or beautify) the text by identifying singularized commas `" , "` and replace them with `", "`.